# How do Idynamically create an input tag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In this program, the first input (textfield) represent the length and after I put a input and after I click the button I would that are creaed a number of text field equal to the input length. My problem is that the first input I capture but I don't know how create dynamically the text field. Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input name="mioTesto" id="mioTesto" type="text" value="" size="40" maxlength="200" />
        <button onclick="catturaValore()">Inserisci Valore</button>
        <script>
            function catturaValore() {

                var valore = document.getElementById("mioTesto").value;
                var maxIndice = parseInt(valore);

                var container = document.getElementById("container");
                for (var i = 0; i < maxIndice; i++) {
                    var input = document.createElement("input" + i)
                    input.name = "mioTesto"
                    input.id = i;
                    input.type = "text";
                    input.size = "40";
                    input.malength = "200";
                    input.className = "css-class-name"; // set
                    container.appendChild(input);
                }
            }
        </script>
        <button onclick="ordinaVettore()">Ordina</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You remove the `+i` as adding a number to the tagname is not valid ?

Comment: @adeneo Doesn't work the same!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
var input=document.createElement("input"+i)
```

to

```
var input=document.createElement("input")
```

so that it is actually a valid element. I assume you wanted to give that as its name or id, like #input1, #input2, etc, in which case you can do:

```
var input = document.createElement("input")
    input.setAttribute('id', 'input'+i)
```

Comment: I modify my code following your suggest but the code doesn't wok!